# отсутствует оператор "<<", соответствующий этим операндам

Tags: c++

Такая проблема - пишу код, совсем простенький на разминку. В онлайн-компиляторе все норм, а в Visual Studio ругается. Обьясните чайнику, что делать? Почему? Как исправить? вот код -

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pch.h"

string str;
cin >> str;
cout << str;
}
```

Comment: `#include "stdafx.h"`

Comment: `#include <string>` еще

Comment: Вы что-то выдумываете. Каким же это образом онлайн компилятор проглотил `#include "pch.h"`? Это не говоря даже о том, что ваш код - это какой-то синтаксически неправильный огрызок..

Comment: Попробуйте подключить библиотеку `#include <String.h>`

Comment: `#include <String.h>`??? Что это за "библиотека"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, если вы включили использование прекомпилированных заголовков в своем проекте, то соответствующий `#include` должен идти самым первым. В вашем случае это, по-видимому, `"pch.h"`

```
#include "pch.h"    // <- должен быть самым первым
#include <iostream>
```

Во-вторых, для использования класса `std::string` нужно еще `#include <string>`.

Answer (score 2):

Пропишите `using namespace std`, либо же везде добавляйте `std::`

Comment: в коде на стаке не появилось почему-то, но ладно. Короче, поставил #include "pch.h" первым - заработало. Но все равно спасибо, что хоть не обосрал код